# How do I fill a text input based on the data attribute of a select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a select box and an input field

```html
<label for="contact">Contact</label>
<select id="contact" name="contact">
    <option data-phone="+14151234567" value="John Smith">John Smith</option>
    <option data-phone="+15151234567" value="Jessica Smith">Jessica Smith</option>
    <option data-phone="+16151234567" value="Jerome Smith">Jerome Smith</option>
</select>

<label for="phone">Phone</label>
<input type="text" name="phone"/>
```

When the user selects an option from the `Contact` select box, I want the option's `data-phone` attribute to be filled in the `Phone` text input.

For the user, they pick a name from a list, and the person's phone number magically autofills in the input fields below

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a [change()](https://api.jquery.com/change/) method that attaches a function to run when a change event occurs. `select` tags work with `change()` method . same as `checkbox` or `radio`

so you need to 'listen' when the `select` is changed and see which of the `options` is selected ( with `option:selected` ) . then 'get' the `data-phone` attribute of the 'selected' option and add it as a 'value' to the input field.

and that's about it

also i suggest you use a 'blank' first option for the select tag. as i have used below ( `<option disabled selected value>` )

let me know if it works. cheers

```js
$("#contact").change(function(){
   var phoneNr = $(this).children("option:selected").attr("data-phone")
   $("input[name='phone']").attr("value",phoneNr)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="contact">Contact</label>
  <select id="contact" name="contact">
    <option disabled selected value> --- select an option --- </option>
    <option data-phone="+14151234567" value="John Smith">John Smith</option>
    <option data-phone="+15151234567" value="Jessica Smith">Jessica Smith</option>
    <option data-phone="+16151234567" value="Jerome Smith">Jerome Smith</option>
  </select>

  <label for="phone">Phone</label>
  <input type="text"  name="phone"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery [`change`](https://api.jquery.com/change/) event,  jQuery [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) and [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) functions:

```js
var $contact = $('#contact');
$contact.on('change', fillPhone);

function fillPhone() {
    $('input[name="phone"]').val(
        $contact.find('option:selected').data('phone')
    );
}

fillPhone();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="contact">Contact</label>
<select id="contact" name="contact">
    <option data-phone="+14151234567" value="John Smith">John Smith</option>
    <option data-phone="+15151234567" value="Jessica Smith">Jessica Smith</option>
    <option data-phone="+16151234567" value="Jerome Smith">Jerome Smith</option>
</select>

<label for="phone">Phone</label>
<input type="text" name="phone"/>
```